# Spring @RestController: should I need to indicate produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in a method explicitely

Tags: spring-mvc

As the title says, I wonder if I still need to declare `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in a controller's method if the controller is already annotated with `@RestController`? I'm working on an old legacy application where all the controller methods have this declared. Spring Boot Initializr generates a default REST controller without it and even if I omit `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`, it still works without any problems.
I remember to have seen somewhere that is supposed to be as default. Correct or not?

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
@Slf4j
public class PostsController {

    @PutMapping(value = "posts/{post_d}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Post> getPost(@PathVariable Long postId) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No. ANd it doesn't do what you think it does. The `produces` attribute is used for mapping an incoming request it is **not** for forcing the result into JSON. the `produces` takes an array of supported `Accept-Header` values (the default is everything). This way you could write 2 request handler methods 1 for JSON and another for XML or HTML or a PDF or ... It will route to the correct method based on the accept-header it will thus NOT enforce anything on the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to acknowledge/remember is that everything in the `@RequestMapping` annotation (or the specialized `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, etc. ) is that it is used for **mapping**. Hence the fact that that thing is named `@RequestMapping`. It does not force anything upon the response being written. In fact the [`produces`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) attribute actually takes an `String[]` so that you can limit for which response types (the `Accept-Header`) this method will match. So if you do `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` only requests that explicitly accept `application/json` in their response will go to this method.

The fact that it is used for mapping/routing makes it useful to have multiple methods for the same URL but producing different results. Lets say you have a request method that produces a report which can be created in XML or PDF. But the PDF is more complex so you need a different method.

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/report", produces = "application/xml")
public ReportXml generateXmlReport() {}

@RequestMapping(value="/report", produces = "application/pdf")
public void generateXmlReport(HttpServletResponse response) {
  // use iText to generate a PDF and directly write to the response
}
```

Now due to the `produces` Spring MVC can use this to route an incoming request to the proper request handling method.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. So, in the case of an API application where all the requests suppose to accept JSON only, could `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` be omitted?

Comment: As mentioned it is only used for mapping not for determining the response type. That will later be done when starting to write the response to get the most applicable response.

Comment: I didn't ask about the response type but about the request. If I get you right, specifying the value in `produces` will limit to the requests that explicitly accept only application/json in their response. Right?

Comment: No it will limit to requests that accept JSON as a response. The `Accept-Header` can have multi[ple accepted response types.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should show us the error occured. Normally, it is not necessary to specify the value of **produces** at the controller level, but at the level of the services that consume it.

Note that the path to test this function is:

```
baseURL/posts/posts/{post_d}
```